# Show tab-pane from a outside link click

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-tabs

I need a `<a href="#" class="link-one">Link</a>` **outside nav-tabs** to activate a tab-panel/tab-content using Bootstrap 5.

Basically, how can I simplify this?

```
// show relevant Bootstrap tab from a outside link click

$('.link-one').on('click', function(){
  $('#tab-one-pane').addClass('show active');
  $('#tab-two-pane').removeClass('show active');
  $('#tab-two').removeClass('active');
  $('#tab-one').addClass('active');
});

$('.link-two').on('click', function(){
  $('#tab-two-pane').addClass('show active');
  $('#tab-one-pane').removeClass('show active');
  $('#tab-one').removeClass('active');
  $('#tab-two').addClass('active');
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class called `link` to your `anchor` tags making the `data-target` attribute your unique IDs

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="link" data-target="#tab-one">Link to Tab One</a>
<a href="#" class="link" data-target="#tab-two">Link to Tab Two</a>
```

JS:

```
   $('.link').on('click', function(e) {
      let target = $(this).data('target');
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + target + '"]').tab('show');
    });
```

This will solve the repeating code.